# Throttle Lambda execution rate from SQS event trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to limit the number of lambdas invoked during a time period given a large SQS queue? e.g max 10 lambda invocations per minute.

I can restrict a lambda to run SQS events synchronously by setting the `ReserveConcurrencyExecution` to 1 and `BatchSize` to 1, but I want the ability to throttle lambda execution further.

I don't want to resort to putting a nasty sleep within the lambda.

Background is that there is a follow-on component which can't handle the bursty nature of our workloads.

Comment: You can do it the opposite way. Instead of setting up event source mapping between sqs and lambda as you have now, put your lambda on a scheduled CloudWatchEvent rule, and query your sqs ever 1min (or what you need) yourself.

Comment: Interesting idea - 1 min precision for CW rule is a bit coarse, but potentially least bad option.

Comment: Step functions also have `Wait` state, with second-level precision. I guess you could make a loop in SF if you want. Alternatively, would be to forfeit lambda, and look make at lightweight container or tiny instance, instead of the lambda function.